# Sorting a row in an Excel file by win32com

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I try to sort a single row in an Excel file with following .py file. My sample data is 90 60 0 60 50 40 80 60 70 70 20 and they take place in the first row of my excel file. Could you please help me correct my code? Thanks in advance.

```
import win32com.client

wbk = 'C:\\Path\\To\\Workbook.xlsx'

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(wbk)

xlAscending = 1
xlDescending = 2
xlSortColumns = 1
xlSortRows = 2    

xlApp.Sheets(1).Range("A1:K1").Sort(Key1=xlApp.Sheets(1).Rows(1), 
                      Order1=xlDescending, Orientation=xlSortRows)

xlApp.Quit
xlApp = None
```

Comment: Do you really need `win32com` here? You can just use something simple like `openpyxl` to do this.

Comment: Hello. Actually, I first tried to do that with openpyxl but could not manage it. Could you please share if you know any way to sort a row (same problem above) by openpyxl? Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your `openpyxl` attemp.

Answer (score 0):

I done this in the past, see if it helps:

```
ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter()
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key=ws.Range("E1"), SortOn=xlSortOnValues, Order=xlDescending, DataOption=xlSortNormal)
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.Header = xlYes
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.MatchCase = False
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.Apply()
```

Corrected:

```
ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter(1)
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key=ws.Range("E1"), SortOn=xlSortOnValues, Order=xlDescending, DataOption=xlSortNormal)
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.Header = xlYes
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.MatchCase = False
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.Apply()
```